# Build Error Exception while loading build-info.xml

Tags: android

When I want to run my project it occurs with some errors,

The error is : 
Exception while loading build-info.xml : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.

Anybody knows the problem ?!

Comment: please post your build-info.xml

Comment: @ItzikSamara where is the directory of this file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution!

In Android Studio, go to : >> Build >> Rebuild Project

and then run the project again.

This works for me, I hope it works for others who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This can be cause by presence of white space before declaring XML often whitespace are ignored most people don't know that it can cause error.
You can share your XML code which will help me to identify where is your error is .